# Android camera application force close

Tags: java, android, camera, android-camera, forceclose

I am building a camera application for android, trying to learn how. I have followed a tutorial, but it keeps failing and force closes. Please take a look at my details below:

Xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/layout">
<TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Camera Demo"
    android:textSize="24sp" />

<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/preview"
    android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
</FrameLayout>

<Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/buttonClick"
    android:text="Click" android:layout_gravity="center"></Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

Java code:

```
public class CameraActivity extends Activity {
private static final String TAG = "CameraDemo";
Camera camera;
Preview preview;
Button buttonClick;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.camera_screen);

    preview = new Preview(this);
    ((FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.preview)).addView(preview);

    buttonClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonClick);
    buttonClick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            preview.camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback,
                    jpegCallback);
        }
    });

    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate'd");
}

ShutterCallback shutterCallback = new ShutterCallback() {
    public void onShutter() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onShutter'd");
    }
};

/** Handles data for raw picture */
PictureCallback rawCallback = new PictureCallback() {
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - raw");
    }
};

/** Handles data for jpeg picture */
PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        FileOutputStream outStream = null;
        try {
            // write to local sandbox file system
            // outStream =
            // CameraDemo.this.openFileOutput(String.format("%d.jpg",
            // System.currentTimeMillis()), 0);
            // Or write to sdcard
            outStream = new FileOutputStream(String.format(
                    "/sdcard/%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis()));
            outStream.write(data);
            outStream.close();
            Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - wrote bytes: " + data.length);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - jpeg");
    }
};

}
```

Preview.java:

```
class Preview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
private static final String TAG = "Preview";

SurfaceHolder mHolder;
public Camera camera;

Preview(Context context) {
    super(context);

    // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
    // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
    mHolder = getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
    mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // The Surface has been created, acquire the camera and tell it where
    // to draw.
    camera = Camera.open();
    try {
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);

        camera.setPreviewCallback(new PreviewCallback() {

            public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera arg1) {
                FileOutputStream outStream = null;
                try {
                    outStream = new FileOutputStream(String.format(
                            "/sdcard/%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis()));
                    outStream.write(data);
                    outStream.close();
                    Log.d(TAG, "onPreviewFrame - wrote bytes: "
                            + data.length);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                }
                Preview.this.invalidate();
            }
        });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // Surface will be destroyed when we return, so stop the preview.
    // Because the CameraDevice object is not a shared resource, it's very
    // important to release it when the activity is paused.
    camera.stopPreview();
    camera = null;
}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
    // Now that the size is known, set up the camera parameters and begin
    // the preview.
    Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
    parameters.setPreviewSize(w, h);
    camera.setParameters(parameters);
    camera.startPreview();
}

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.draw(canvas);
    Paint p = new Paint(Color.RED);
    Log.d(TAG, "draw");
    canvas.drawText("PREVIEW", canvas.getWidth() / 2,
            canvas.getHeight() / 2, p);
}
}
```

Logcat:

```
02-01 19:44:41.825: E/AndroidRuntime(4329): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-01 19:44:41.825: E/AndroidRuntime(4329): java.lang.RuntimeException: setParameters failed
02-01 19:44:41.825: E/AndroidRuntime(4329):     at android.hardware.Camera.native_setParameters(Native Method)
02-01 19:44:41.825: E/AndroidRuntime(4329):     at android.hardware.Camera.setParameters(Camera.java:1527)
02-01 19:44:41.825: E/AndroidRuntime(4329):     at com.mysoftware.mysoftwareos.mobile.Preview.surfaceChanged(Preview.java:78)
02-01 19:44:41.825: E/AndroidRuntime(4329):     at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:554)
02-01 19:44:41.825: E/AndroidRuntime(4329):     at android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:81)
02-01 19:44:41.825: E/AndroidRuntime(4329):     at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:169)
02-01 19:44:41.825: E/AndroidRuntime(4329):     at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:671)
02-01 19:44:41.825: E/AndroidRuntime(4329):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1848)
02-01 19:44:41.825: E/AndroidRuntime(4329):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1028)
02-01 19:44:41.825: E/AndroidRuntime(4329):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4246)
02-01 19:44:41.825: E/AndroidRuntime(4329):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
02-01 19:44:41.825: E/AndroidRuntime(4329):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
02-01 19:44:41.825: E/AndroidRuntime(4329):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
02-01 19:44:41.825: E/AndroidRuntime(4329):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
02-01 19:44:41.825: E/AndroidRuntime(4329):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
02-01 19:44:41.825: E/AndroidRuntime(4329):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-01 19:44:41.825: E/AndroidRuntime(4329):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-01 19:44:41.825: E/AndroidRuntime(4329):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4765)
02-01 19:44:41.825: E/AndroidRuntime(4329):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-01 19:44:41.825: E/AndroidRuntime(4329):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-01 19:44:41.825: E/AndroidRuntime(4329):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
02-01 19:44:41.825: E/AndroidRuntime(4329):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
02-01 19:44:41.825: E/AndroidRuntime(4329):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-01 19:44:45.455: E/Trace(4386): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
02-01 19:44:45.585: E/PhonePolicy(4386): Could not preload class for phone policy: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$ContextMenuCallback
```

Please help me and thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

You don't have the source for the Preview class shown, so it's very hard to say what might be wrong.

But from the trace, the error is from a Camera.setParameters() call from Preview.surfaceChanged. So the question is, what are you trying to set there that the camera doesn't like?

Also, your log only covers exactly the exception, so there's no context about what the system was doing right before your failure. Including a bit of the log before the failure would be very helpful for debugging as well; the system often prints out a reason as to why the call failed a few lines before the stack trace.

Edit: Now with Preview.java there, I can see the problem.

You can't pick a random size for the camera preview output. It has to be one of the preview sizes provided by [getSupportedPreviewSizes()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getSupportedPreviewSizes%28%29). Right now, you're just using the size of the Surface for the preview output, which is not guaranteed to work at all (you might get lucky if the size matches one on the list, but that's unlikely).

Take a look at the [camera app tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#custom-camera) on the Android developer's site; it tries to cover some of these details.

Comment: I uploaded the preview class if you could take a look at it